# Why are widgets not created at __init__ function?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy so I'm trying to do an App, useful to me, to learn this framework.

My need is to manage my shift work schedule so I started inserting calendar days into a `GridLayout`. After several troubles now I'm blocked because I've got this error:

```
File "turno.py", line 53, in load_content    
  self.gridMonthView.add_widget(DaysInfo(day=wid))  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'
```

The `load_content` is called from inside the `__init__` function, the error happens when I try to add `DaysInfo` widget (one for each day of the current month).

The strange (for me) behaviour is that if I comment line n.47 (that calls the `load_content` method) the program goes running and then I'm able to use the `load_content` from inside functions `prevMonth` and `nextMonth` without having any error.

So the question is:

- Why does it seem that inside the `__init__` method I can't use `add_widget` for `gridMonthView` reference/object but it's possible from the other methods of the same class?
- Maybe that is not possible to add widget before the `__init__` function ends something that I don't know/understand?

So, here's the code:

1. A little module to handle dates: `calendario.py`

   ```
   from calendar import Calendar
   from datetime import date

   IT_months = ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile',\
                 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto',\
                 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre']

   IT_days = ['Lunedi',
              'Martedi',
              'Mercoledi',
              'Giovedi',
              'Venerdi',
              'Sabato',
              'Domenica']


   class Calendario():

       def __init__ (self):

           self.currDay = date.today()
           self.calen = Calendar(0)
           # def __init__ (self):

       def getMonth(self):
           return IT_months[self.currDay.month-1]
           # def getMonth(self):

       def getYear(self):
           return str(self.currDay.year)
           # def getYear(self):

       def getDaysOfMonth(self, listOfDays):
           listOfDays = []
           for td in self.calen.itermonthdates(self.currDay.year, self.currDay.month):
               listOfDays.append(td.day)
               # for td in ...

           return listOfDays
           # def getDaysOfMonth(self, listOfDays):

       def setNextMonth(self):
           if self.currDay.month == 12:
               self.currDay = self.currDay.replace(month=1, year=(self.currDay.year+1))
           else:
               self.currDay = self.currDay.replace(month=(self.currDay.month+1))
           # def setNextMonth(self):

       def setPrevMonth(self):
           if self.currDay.month == 1:
               self.currDay = self.currDay.replace(month=12, year=(self.currDay.year-1))
           else:
               self.currDay = self.currDay.replace(month=(self.currDay.month-1))
           # def setNextMonth(self):
   ```
2. the .kv file: `turno.kv`

   ```
   #:kivy 1.9.0
   # 
   # menu bar
   #
   <MenuBar>:
       orientation: 'horizontal'
       padding: 1
       spacing: 1
       size_hint_y: 0.15
       Button:
           text: "Icon"
           size_hint_x: 0.3
           on_press: root.menu()
       Button:
           text: "Title"
           #size_hint: 1, 0.5


   #
   # day's info 
   #
   <DaysInfo>:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       padding: 1
       spacing: 1
       Label:
           color: 1,0,0,1
           background_color: 1,1,1,1
           id: f1
           text: " "
       Label:
           id: f2
           text: " "
       Label:
           id: f3
           text: " "


   #
   # month view
   #
   <MonthView>:
       gridMonthView: gridMonthView
       #
       orientation: "vertical"
       #
       # month selection
       #
       BoxLayout:
           id: box1
           orientation: 'horizontal'
           padding: 1
           spacing: 1
           size_hint_y: 0.15
           Button:
               backgroud_color: 0,1,0,1
               text: " << "
               size_hint_x: 0.1
               on_press: root.prevMonth()
           Button:
               id: idSelMonth
               text: root.curMonth
               size_hint_x: 0.5
           Button:
               id: isSelYear
               text: root.curYear
               size_hint_x: 0.3
           Button:
               text: " >> "
               size_hint_x: 0.1
               on_press: root.nextMonth()
       #
       # week's days
       #
       BoxLayout:
           id: box2
           orientation: 'horizontal'
           padding: 1
           spacing: 1
           color: 0., 0.5, 0.5, 1
           size_hint_y: 0.1
           Label:
               text: "Lu"
           Label:
               text: "Ma"
           Label:
               text: "Me"
           Label:
               text: "Gi"
           Label:
               text: "Ve"
           Label:
               text: "Sa"
           Label:
               text: "Do"
       #
       # Month's days
       #
       GridLayout:
           id: gridMonthView
           cols: 7
           rows: 6
           padding: 1
           spacing: 1
           size_hint_y: 0.6

   #
   # Turno Main Form
   #
   <TurnoMainForm>:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       padding: 20
       spacing: 10
       #width: 400
       #height: 800

       # menu bar
       MenuBar:

       # month view
       MonthView:
           id: id1
   ```
3. the app's source code: `turno.py`

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   """
   Created on Mon Oct 06 12:25:04 2015

   @author: a809077
   """

   from kivy.app import App
   from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
   from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
   from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
   from kivy.config import Config

   from calendario import Calendario

   # impostazione della grandezza della finestra
   Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
   Config.set('graphics', 'height', '800')

   class MenuBar(BoxLayout):

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super(MenuBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           print ("------- MenuBar -------")
           for child in self.children:
               print(child)

       def menu (self):
           print (" ====== click sul menu ======")
       # end of class: MenuBar(BoxLayout)

   ##
   ## visualizza i dati mensili    
   ##
   class MonthView(BoxLayout):

       gridMonthView = ObjectProperty(None)

       curMonth = StringProperty()
       curYear = StringProperty()

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           print ("------- Month View -------")
           self.curMonth = TurnoApp.currCal.getMonth()
           self.curYear = TurnoApp.currCal.getYear()
           super(MonthView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           self.load_content(True)
           self.printInfo()

       def load_content(self, clearWidget = False):
           if (clearWidget):
               print "---- Clear Widgets ----"
               self.gridMonthView.clear_widgets()

           lod = list ()
           lod = TurnoApp.currCal.getDaysOfMonth(lod)
           for wid in lod:
               self.gridMonthView.add_widget(DaysInfo(day=wid))

       def prevMonth (self):
           print (" ====== click sul mese precedente 1 ======")
           TurnoApp.currCal.setPrevMonth()
           self.curMonth = TurnoApp.currCal.getMonth()
           self.curYear = TurnoApp.currCal.getYear()
           #self.printInfo()
           self.load_content(True)

       def nextMonth (self):
           print (" ====== click sul mese successivo ======")
           TurnoApp.currCal.setNextMonth()
           self.curMonth = TurnoApp.currCal.getMonth()
           self.curYear = TurnoApp.currCal.getYear()
           #self.printInfo()
           self.load_content(True)

       def printInfo (self):
           print " ____ items ____"
           for key, val in self.ids.items():
               print("key={0}, val={1}".format(key, val))
           print " ____ childs ____"
           for child in self.children:
               print("{} -> {}".format(child, child.id))
           print " ____ walk ____"
           for obj in self.walk():
               print obj
       # end of class: MonthView(GridLayout):


   class DaysInfo(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super(DaysInfo, self).__init__()
           #print ("-- Days Info - {:d} ------".format(kwargs["day"]))
           self.ids["f1"].text =str(kwargs["day"])       
       # end of class: DaysInfo(BoxLayout):


   class TurnoMainForm(BoxLayout):

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super(TurnoMainForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
           print ("-------TurnoMainForm-------")
           for child in self.children:
               print(child)
       # end of class: TurnoMainForm(BoxLayout):


   class TurnoApp (App):
       # icon = 'mia_icona.png'
       title = 'Turno Terna'
       currCal = Calendario()

       def build (self):
           return TurnoMainForm()
           #return MonthView()

       # end of class: TurnoApp (App):


   TurnoApp().run()
   ```

I don't try to reduce the code to an example, instead I post everything because it may be better to understand where the problem is and to give me some tip to improve the code.

Comment: You are right that posting everything instead of a reduction can help finding the problem, but it also means that it takes more effort. A *good* reduction keeps everything that is necessary to reproduce the problem, and removes everything else. Please edit your post, removing all what is not strictly related to the problem. You can have a look at the suggestions to write a [mcve]. Anyway, welcome to SO!

Comment: I red mcve guide lines and I'll try to follow them next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it seem that inside the **init** method I can't use add_widget for gridMonthView reference/object but it's possible from the other methods of the same class?

Because self.gridMonthView has not yet been set yet (i.e. modified from the default value of None) within the `__init__`. This is a technical limitation - imagine two widgets with kv rules that reference one another, in this case at least one of them can't reference the other in its `__init__` because it will be the first one to actually have been instantiated. This is the kind of effect you see here, the widgets must all be instantiated before references between them can be set.

It works in other methods because you call them only later, after all the instantiation is complete.

You can use something like `Clock.schedule_once(self.post_init, 0)` and put your widget addition in the post_init method; scheduling with an interval of 0 makes sure it will happen before the next frame, but after everything currently in progress has completed.

Comment: Just another question: Maybe that this limitation will change in a future? May be useful to insert an on_post_init member in the widget class definition?

Comment: We've been considering adding such an event though it would only implement the Clock scheduling as an automatic thing.